# SAPUI5 Smart table expand

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

Using the publicly available Nortwhind oData v2 service I can expand on Product and Supplier entity in a normal sap.m.Table using the following code:

```
<Table 
    id="table" 
    width="auto" 
    class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" 
    items="{ 
        path: '/Products', 
        parameters : { expand: 'Supplier' } 
    }">
    <columns>
        <Column id="nameColumn">
            <Text 
                text="{i18n>tableNameColumnTitle}" 
                id="nameColumnTitle" />
        </Column>
        <Column hAlign="End">
            <Text text="test" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem 
            type="Navigation" 
            press="onPress">
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{ProductName}"/>
                <Text text="{Supplier/CompanyName}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Now how can I achieve the same output using a smart table? Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996305/bind-smarttable-with-entityset-of-an-entity) I tried the following:

```
<sap.ui.comp.smarttable:SmartTable 
    xmlns:sap.ui.comp.smarttable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable" 
    tableType="ResponsiveTable" 
    header="Smart Table"
    enableAutoBinding="true" 
    entitySet="Products" 
    initiallyVisibleFields="ProductName" 
    tableBindingPath="Supplier"/>
```

But it is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have moved a step further. I have added the following code:
>
> ```
> onBeforeRebind: function(oEvent) { var mBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
> mBindingParams.parameters["expand"] = "Supplier"; },
> ```

well that's it for how using $expand on Smarttables

> Is there any way to display columns from the other entity?

Only via NavigationProperty. You need to extend your smarttable columns like mentioned bellow:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable 
        entitySet="Products"
        tableType="ResponsiveTable"
        header="Products" showRowCount="true"
        enableAutoBinding="true"
        class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
        <Table>
            <columns>
                <Column width="100px" hAlign="Left">
                    <customData>
                        <core:CustomData key="p13nData"
                            value='\{"columnKey": "p13nDataKey",  "columnIndex":"4", "leadingProperty": "Supplier"}' />
                    </customData>
                    <Text text="{/#Supplier/Name/@sap:label}" />
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <Text
                            text="{Supplier/Name}" />
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
    </smartTable:SmartTable>
```

Comment: Hi Haos, do you know how to filter /sorter  or group column Supplier/Name? I can filter the other column of Product's table unless columns of Supplier's table (I mean the collection's table) .Thanks ...Dieu

Answer (score 0):

I have moved a step further. I have added the following code:

```
    onBeforeRebind: function(oEvent) {
var mBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
    mBindingParams.parameters["expand"] = "Supplier";
},
```

which kicks on beforeRebindTable event. It triggers the get expanded entity set in the backend. The problem is that I still can only see columns from the first entity as it is specified in the entitySet parameter. Is there any way to display columns from the other entity?